# How can I read a csv file as a dictionary such that the keys are tuples

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file and I'm trying to read it such that the keys would be a tuple. I'm relatively new to the language and the only other language I'm familiar with is C. Here is the csv file:

```
name,ABC,DEF,GHI
Alan,2,8,3
Barry,4,1,5
Collin,3,2,5
```

My desired dictionary would be:

```
{
    (2,8,3):"Alan"
    (4,1,5):"Barry"
    (3,2,5):"Collin"
}
```

This is the code I have now. Its bugged because I tried to store the key as a list instead of a tuple. However, I'm not too sure how to go about changing it. Any help would be really great.

```
dictionary = {}
with open(argv[1], "r") as file:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader1:
        key = row[1:]
        dictionary[key] = row[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
dictionary = {}
with open(argv[1], "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # skip header
    for line in reader:
        dictionary[tuple(map(int, line[1:]))] = line[0]

    print(dictionary)
```

This prints:

```
{(2, 8, 3): 'Alan', (4, 1, 5): 'Barry', (3, 2, 5): 'Collin'}
```

Comment: after getting the dictionary, is there anyway I have access to the individual values in the tuple?

Comment: @ffriends_ Yep, you can do that, just use indexing with the key of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

> Create an object that operates like a regular reader but maps the information in each row to a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) whose keys are given by the optional fieldnames parameter.

`DictReader` will map your row to a dictionary. What you are currently doing is slicing dictionary with `row[1:]`, which won't work and give you a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'` exception.

Instead, you could filter all items which don't have `name` key with a `tuple` [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). Then you can simply use this as the key and set the value as `name`.

```
import csv

dictionary = {}
with open(argv[1], "r") as file:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader1:
        rows = tuple(int(v) for k, v in row.items() if k != "name")
        dictionary[rows] = row["name"]

print(dictionary)
```

**Output:**

```
{(2, 8, 3): 'Alan', (4, 1, 5): 'Barry', (3, 2, 5): 'Collin'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explaination but could I trouble you to explain this line of code? `rows = tuple(int(v) for k, v in row.items() if k != "name")` I kinda figured that I would group the numbers into a tuple but I'm not too sure exactly what it means.

Comment: @ffriends_ It filters every value from the `key:values` inside the dictionary where the key name is not equal to `"name"`. If you do `print(row)`, you can see what the whole dictionary looks like, and that my tuple expression simply removes the `"name"` key and creates a `tuple`.

Comment: @ffriends_ Does that make sense? If not we can go into a chat room and I can explain more.

Comment: Yup makes sense! I figured the problem I had has also got to do with my understanding towards csv files. I find it hard to work with python because unlike c, I have to be very explicit about everything so I find it challenging to adapt to this new language. Thank you for taking your time to explain I understand it better now.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

import pandas as pd
Csv=pd.read_csv('somecsvfile.csv')

Dictcsv=Csv.to_dict()

## your dict is ready

Comment: This won't use the tupels as keys to the dictionary, which was the question.